# passing control to another page with link does not send variables to the other page

Tags: php, html

Since I'm a newbie, I might be doing a lot of bad steps and with that making mistakes that I just can't figure out.
The first  sets up the uid, pwd. A second one sets the fname. 
The lines below were created by the following code:

```
   session_start();
if (isset($_POST['fname']))
{
$uid    =   $_POST['uid'];                  #   $uid contains "myname"
$pwd    =   $_POST['pwd'];                  #   $pwd contains "myapss"
$fname  =   $_POST['fname'];            #   $fname contains "john doe"    as expected...
echo $uid.$pwd.$fname;              #   This echo confirms that the variavbles were received (debugging only)
$_SESSION   = $uid;             #------------------
}
else
whatever
```

This is where I'm having trouble:
I set up the < href=   as follows :  (the "a" was removed from this post as it it reserved word).

```
    $hrefed     =   ('<  href="edit_user.php?');
$hrefed     .=  ("{id='$uid' ,");
$hrefed     .=  ("pwd='$pwd' ,"); 
$hrefed     .=  ("fname='$fname'}"); 
$hrefed     .=  ('">Edit Selected Info</a>');
```

and it translates to:

```
    <  href="edit_user.php?{id='myname' ,pwd='mypass' ,fname='john doe'}">Edit Selected  Info</a>
```

When clicking on the link created to pass control to another program I get the message that  no variables were  Posted.
Can someone give me some idea what is the correct way to set up the  call  parameters to the other page

Thank You and have a nice Thanksgiving.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$hrefed     =   ('<a href="edit_user.php?');
$hrefed     .=  ("&id=$uid");
$hrefed     .=  ("&pwd=$pwd"); 
$hrefed     .=  ("&fname=$fname"); 
$hrefed     .=  ('">Edit Selected Info</a>');
```

What you're creating here is called a GET query string. Read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Also, use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST` in your script:

```
if (isset($_GET['fname']))
{
$uid    =   $_GET['uid'];                  #   $uid contains "myname"
$pwd    =   $_GET['pwd'];                  #   $pwd contains "myapss"
$fname  =   $_GET['fname'];            #   $fname contains "john doe"    as expected...
echo $uid.$pwd.$fname;              #   This echo confirms that the variavbles were received (debugging only)
$_SESSION   = $uid;             #------------------
}
```

Read more about HTTP request methods here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GET_(HTTP)#Request_methods

These will solve your immediate problem.

The more serious problem is that **you shouldn't just print a user's password on a web page**. You shouldn't even *store* the password, only a hash of it. If this is just a hobby project, that's OK but please remember to do some research about basic web security before making a real-world web site.

See:

- [How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php)
- [What should every programmer know about web development?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-every-programmer-know-about-web-development)

Comment: Balasz,Koszonom segitsegedet. Thanks for your help. I'll look up the links you've pointed me to.

Comment: Nagyon szívesen :) I'm glad I could help and thanks for taking the time to respond in my native language.

Comment: En nem nem Magayroesagban szulletem, if you wish, Irjal pkhuskydusky at gmail.com. Your example worked perfectly and once again thank you for the help.

Comment: @Balazs, I have the following problem now and I'd ask for your help.

Comment: @Balazs, I have the following problem now and I'd ask for your help. Given:  `echo ('<  href="edit_info.php?&id=$nome&user=$fname">Edit Selected Info</a>');`  how do I capture the $nome and $fname  in edit_info.php?  I can't get hold of the two variables. If you could explain how this would work I'd appreciate.  Udvozollek,  Peter